Can I drywall over fiberboard?
I bought a 1960s home with interior walls of fiberboard which were then wall papered.
Can I drywall over top the fiberboard? What preparation would be needed?
I worry about moisture buildup as the house has a laid stone foundation and can be damp at times.

Fiberboard, as in MDF?

Where are you, in the world?

wood pulp fibreboard, or fiber cement... not that it really makes much difference, if you can get screws or nails into studs you can attach drywall,

I'm located in north central Pennsylvania. The product I have on the walls is very soft. You can break it easily . It appears to be made of wood slivers with a brown or black coating on the face.. Should I apply a moisture barrier before the drywall. ?

wood pulp fibreboard, high, medium or low density, even fiber-cement: all have been used as wall linings; and it doesn't really make much difference for this question.
If you can get screws or nails into studs you can attach drywall.
Asbestos might be a risk for 1960s fiber cement. so if that's what you've got take apropriate steps.

Thank you .  The product is extremely soft. Seems to be made of wood slivers compressed. Surface is brown or black , thin coating.

low density fibreboard,  not real popular with the fire safety guys.

You can apply drywall over any existing finish.
For best anchorage, determine the location of the underlying studs and fasten the drywall to them rather than the sheathing, to reduce the possibility of nail pops.
You will require electrical box extensions to compensate for the additional depth.

Thank you  kindly.
